# Make a loop in R from first value of a column to last value of a column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, time-series

How can I make a loop in R that operates from the first row of a column to the end of that column? something like **from x[1,2] to tail(x[,2], n=1)**

Comment: Depends on the operation. R is a vectorized language thus making operations columnar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `nrow`.

```
(m <- matrix(1:18, 6, 3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    7   13
# [2,]    2    8   14
# [3,]    3    9   15
# [4,]    4   10   16
# [5,]    5   11   17
# [6,]    6   12   18

for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
  m[i, 2] <- m[i, 2] + 100
  }
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1  107   13
# [2,]    2  108   14
# [3,]    3  109   15
# [4,]    4  110   16
# [5,]    5  111   17
# [6,]    6  112   18
```

However, since R is vectorized you may take the whole column and do vector operations.

```
m[, 3] <- m[, 3] + 100
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1  107  113
# [2,]    2  108  114
# [3,]    3  109  115
# [4,]    4  110  116
# [5,]    5  111  117
# [6,]    6  112  118
```